# in which layer implement validator dao response?

Tags: java, validation, service, exception, dao

I have a DAO which makes a call to a REST WS. In order to prevent non-valid data sent by the WS, i want to implement a validator.

Where must i implement it ?

1 - in the dao layer, inside the DAO object.

2 - in the dao layer but in a separate class, as the DAO must only do CRUD

3 - in the service layer

Other question : i want to throw an exception when a non-valid data occurs.

Checked or Unchecked ?

I precise that i use Spring Security and when i will call my Service, i will have to catch this exception in order to transform it in an AuthenticationException spring exception.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who has the knowledge required to validate the data being sent back from the WS. If the service has the knowledge ( likely becuase it is creating the data at the first place , but not guarenteed ) , then let the validation be done by the service. It can throw validation failed exception as a normal java component would throw ( this gets wrapped in a SoapException when it appears at client ).

If the validation rules are known only to the client , then I would write another layer and call it from within the DAO.